# C++ char to int conversion for numbers greater than 9

Tags: c++, string, int

I am trying to convert char number values to integers in c++.
For example :

```
char x ='0';
int intX = x-'0';
```

this works but when i am trying to do the same thing with numbers that are greater than 10 it freaks out.
For example :

```
char onuc = '13';
cout<<int(onuc);
```

The outpus is 51.

Please help thanks:)

Comment: Use `std::stoi`. Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol.

Comment: Whats wrong with atoi ?

Comment: it works in the first case because you are substracting the ascii code of `'0'` from `x`. It doesn't work for larger numbers because you can't substract an ascii code from a string.

Comment: @Calips: not necessarily ascii, any supported encoding will work.

Comment: @Bathsheba True, I meant all numbers under 10 are sequential...

Comment: `'13'` is a multi-character constant, how those work are dependent on the compiler (it's not specified). Perhaps you want `"13"` (note the *double* quotes) for which there are functions to convert it already.

Comment: Did you notice that `13` is two characters? A `char` holds one character; one character cannot be two characters.

Comment: @Bathsheba • true, I've deleted my comment.  What was I thinking?  Insufficient coffee error.

Comment: @Eljay: Well at least that one is a trivial fix ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `x - '0'` idiom only works since the characters 0 to 9 are arranged in a contiguous block. (The C++ standard requires that).

But `'13'` is a *multicharacter constant* with an implementation defined value. It is an `int` type so your assignment to `char` is a lossy transformation in general. `'1' * 256 + '3'` is a common implementation.

So alas this approach doesn't work, something like

```
int intX = std::stoi("13");
```

however will.

Comment: thanks everyone :) yes you are right and stoi did my job appreciated

Answer (score 1):

What you are actually doing in the second case is to cast a multi-character into an int type. Multi-characters are implemented differently than normal characters, which are nothing but ascii codes.
The value of the multi-character `'13'` would be derived as `'1'*256+'3'` which is 12592 (I believe it is dependent on the compiler).

For some more examples `int('abcd') = 1633837924` is calculated as :

'a'*256<sup>3</sup> + 'b'*256<sup>2</sup> + 'c'*256 + 'd'

I hope this answer helps you.